# Problema al pedir un entero con Scanner.nextInt() e Ingresar un cero "0" en Java

Tags: java, consola, scanner, java-util-scanner, salto-de-linea

El problema que tengo es con un código en el que estoy trabajando con varias clases,etc.
Lo que sucede es que al inicio del Main creo un Objeto de una clase llamada "*EntradaEcuacion*":

```
public class ProblemaFundamentalMain {
public  static void main(String[] args) {
    
    EntradaEcuacion ec = new EntradaEcuacion();        
    ec.pedirEcuacion();
    ec.simplificarEcuacion();
    ec.imprimirEcuacion();
    
    int [] ecuacion = ec.getExp();
    String [] variable = ec.getVar();
    boolean esEcuacion = ec.isEsEcuacion();
```

y llamo al método "*pedirEcuacion*":

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class EntradaEcuacion {
    //vars de instancia
       
    private int exp [] = new int [3]; //datos de entrada
    
    private String var [] = {"a", "b", " c"}; //Strings para desplegar 
    
    private boolean esEcuacion = true;
    
    // Metodos 
    
    public void pedirEcuacion (){        
        
        Scanner Scanear = new Scanner (System.in); //objeto tipo Scanner
    
        System.out.println("\tSOLUCIONADOR DEL 1er PROBLEMA FUNDAMENTAL");
        System.out.println("\n Ingrese a continuacion los valores de la ecuacion*\t " + "\b*De la forma: aX+bY+c=0");
        System.out.println();
         
        for (int i = 0; i < exp.length ; i++) { // se pide en ciclo los valores de la ecuacion

            System.out.print( " Valor de " + var[i] + " -> " );
            exp[i]= Scanear.nextInt();
        }
        
        if( exp[0] ==0 & exp[1] ==0){
            esEcuacion=false;
        }
    }
```

Cabe mencionar que **antes no causaba ningún problema** pero ahora cuando me pide los valores de 'exp' **si ingreso un valor de 0** la consola se "*queda en el limbo*", y no continua con el código, estoy trabajando en NeatBeans intente cerrar y volver a abrirlo por si era problema del IDE pero sigue igual. Igual estuve verificando por si encontraba algún error pero no fue así.

Les dejo una imagen de la consola

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la flecha de arriba se ve cuando ingreso un 0 y abajo lo que les decía acerca de que "*se queda en el limbo*"

Comment: Hola Brandon, estaría bien que incluyeras el resto de métodos de tu clase EntradaEcuacion que además estás invocando. Y otra cosa aunque no te de error de compilación no te aconsejo usar palabras reservadas en nombre de variables, métodos etc Te lo comento por tu Array de datos de entrada que tiene el nombre de var. QUe es una palabra reservada que se puede usar para en la declaración de una variable no especificar el tipo de datos de la misma, por ejemplo: var num; luego cuando se le asigna un valor a num, se hace la inferencia del tipo. Igualmente te aconsejo hacer un Debug File paso a paso

Comment: Hola gracias, perdon por la demora, ya hice lo que me aconsejaste de cambiar el nombre de "var" para evitar usar una palabra reservada. Tambien hice el Debug step by step en Neatbeans y no encontre nada mal, de hecho con el Debug funcionaba bien no se quedaba "trabado", si avanzaba a la siguiente ejecucion, ese dia deje el programa por algunas horas y en la tarde volvi, y para mi sopresa ya funcionaba, Gracias por la Ayuda y los consejos

Answer (score 1):

Al crear el objeto estas llamando al constructor por defecto, pero no veo que lo tengas creado. Debes crear como mínimo el constructor por defecto del objeto o te acarreará mas problemas a futuro, y recuerda no utilizar palabras reservadas como var en la creación de variables.

```
public EntradaEcuacion(){
      this.exp=exp;
      this.var=var;
}
```

Comment: Si no especificas un constructor, todas las clases siempre tendrán el constructor por defecto... Por eso se le llama *por defecto* :)

Answer (score 1):

**Es conocido que `nextInt()` causa problemas [link1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/why-is-scanner-skipping-nextline-after-use-of-other-next-functions/) [link2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R2ZB-Ye6GEo)
porque deja el cursor en la misma linea de ingreso del input del usuario.**

Además, si no haces validacion del tipo de dato, por ejemplo, si ingreso una letra, se tranca el programa, si ingreso una linea vacia, tambien.

Una forma correcta seria:

1. Usar un do-while loop para validar el input cada vez que se ingresa.
2. Para evitar el error de `nextInt()` usar `scanner.nextLine()`.
3. Guardar el input en una variable en cada iteración para poder validarla.
4. Si las validaciones son satisfactorias, break el while.
5. Parsear el input que ya sabes que es válido a int.

```java
String input;
do{
    System.out.print( " Valor de " + var[i] + " -> " );
    input = scanner.nextLine();
    if(!input.isEmpty()){
        if(input.getText().matches("^\\d+$")){
            break;
        }else{
            System.out.printf("\"%s\" no es un número válido", input);
        }
    }
}while(true);

exp[i]= Integer.parseInt(input);
```

La regex que valida el int es solo para enteros, si decides aceptar floats, deberias cambiar la regex y el parseInt().

Comment: Lo que me indicas lo tengo pensado realizar cuando cree la GUI del programa, por el momento solo estaba centrado en que los algoritmos funcionaran, gracias por la ayuda igual